# Prototype get by tag function

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

How do I get an element or element list by it's tag name. Take for example that I want all elements from `<h1></h1>`.
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 6, accepted):

document.getElementsByTagName('a') returns an array. Look here for more information: http://web.archive.org/web/20120511135043/https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName

Amendment: If you want a real array, you should use something like `Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('a'))`, or these days you'd probably want `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a'))`. Maybe polyfill `Array.from()` if your browser does not support it yet. I can recommend https://polyfill.io/v2/docs/ very much (not affiliated in any way)

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`, similar in many ways to an `Array` but not an `Array`. Maybe the term collection should be used as opposed to array.

Answer (score 4):

Use `$$()` and pass in a CSS selector.

Read the [Prototype API documentation for `$$()`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar)

This gives you more power beyond just tag names. You can select by class, parent/child relationships, etc. It supports more CSS selectors than the common browser can be expected to.

Answer (score 1):

Matthias Kestenholz:

getElementsByTagName returns a NodeList object, which is array-like but is not an array, it's a live list.

```
var test = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
alert(test.length); // n
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
alert(test.length); // n + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `$$(tag-name)[n]` to get specific element from the collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you use getElementsByTagName, you'll need to wrap it in $A() to return an Array.  However, you can simply do $$('a') as nertzy suggested.